# ActiveRecord: Multiple Hash conditions syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to select all users who have a valid department.

```
User
 .joins( orders: [{ order_lines: :accounts}] )
 .where( users: {id: @user}, accounts: { "accounts.dept_id > ?": 0 } )
```

I get the error below,

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting => ...accounts.dept_id > ?": 0 } )
```

I appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: Paul Richter's answer below is correct. I just wanted to point out that the specific reason for the SyntaxError is that when initializing a Hash the colon can only be used for Symbol keys, e.g. `{ foo: 1 }` has the key `:foo`. For keys that are Strings (or other non-Symbols), you need to use the "fat arrow syntax": `{ "foo bar" => 2 }`. Like I said, though, Paul's answer has the solution to your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't really combine the hash and string Active Record method call variants like that.

I think the cleanest approach is to simply make two `.where` calls, like so:

```
...where( users: {id: @user}).where("accounts.dept_id > ?", 0)
```

Comment: *Side Note:* I've never used it, but if you're interested, I believe the [`squeel` gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) allows you to write your AR queries in Ruby without resorting to strings; so your query won't look quite like you had it, but you can do the ` > 0` portion quite easily and nicely.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. squeel looks like a powerful gem and I will give that a try.